# extraction of letters at even positions in strings?

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

```
string extract(string scrambeledword){ 

unsigned int index;
string output;
string input= " ";

for (index=0; index <= scrambeledword.length() ; index++);
{
    if (index%2==0)
    {  
        output+=input ; 
        cout << output; 

    }


}

return output;}
```

I want to extract the even numbered indexed letters from the 40 letter long word inputted by users. does this make sense? i have not taken arrays yet and do not want to include them.

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution? Given some input, let's say "HelloWorld" what does your program output now? What do you **expect** it to output?

Comment: i would expect the output to be "Hlool" to be the output as i just extracted the letters with an even number index

Comment: Okay...and what does your code **actually** do?

Comment: You have a `;` at the end of the for. That means the index will be the length of the word when you are at the `if (index%2==0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems:
1. You have a `;` after your `for` loop, the loop body is never run.
2. `<=` is wrong here since scrambeledword.length() is out of range. Use `!=` or `<` instead.
3. You need to either assign something to `input` before adding it to output or get rid of it altogether.
4. As @Aconcagua pointed out, it is worth noting that I removed your declaration of `index` from the function scope and added it only to the `for` loop scope. If you also considered doing so, compiler would throw an error (since it'd be undeclared outside of the scope of `for`) and you'd be noted about the `;` problem.

Fixed version:

```
string extract(const string &scrambeledword){ // copying strings is expensive

  // unsigned int index;   // obsolete
  string output;
  // string input= " ";    // obsolete

  for (size_t index = 0; index != scrambeledword.length(); ++index) // `<=` would be wrong since scrambeledword.length() is out of range
  {
    if (index % 2 == 0)
    {
      output += scrambeledword[index];
      // cout << output; // obsolete. If you just want the characters, print scrambeledword[index]
      cout << scrambeledword[index];
    }
  }
  cout << endl; // break the line for better readability 
  return output;
}
```

Comment: Better add a `std::endl` after output, otherwise would be difficult to separate the single words. I'd appreciate if you were more explicit about having limited the scope of index variable to the for loop - especially as it would have made the surplus semicolon obvious (undeclared variable in subsequent block -> compilation error).

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks for the suggestions, edited the post and added them. I initially didn't have `std::endl` there because OP didn't have it either and I was not sure about his/her intention.

Comment: this isnt really giving me a single line though, its extracting the letters in a new line everytime

Comment: @HaidyE Can you add what your expected output is for "HelloWorld"? Then I can modify the answer to be more helpful. It is a bit hard to tell what you exactly want to do.

Comment: i just want the even indexes of the string HelloWorld which will give it as an extracted text in one line: Hlool

Comment: @HaidyE Edited and now it does exactly what you want. Please make sure to accept the answer for further reference if it was helpful. Ask for further clarification otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't run the block under the for because there is a `;` at the end of the line. That means the for runs without block. Basically it will count to the length of the given word.

In the for `index <= scrambeledword.length()` can cause an out of bound exception because you can index out of the string-array. Use `index < scrambeledword.length()` instead.

This can be a good solution for the problem:

```
string extract(const string& scrambeledword)
{
    string output;

    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < scrambeledword.length(); index++)
    {
        if (index % 2 == 0)
        {
            output += scrambeledword[index];
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
auto str = "HelloWorld"s;
int  i   = 0;
for_each(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), [&i](char const & c) { if (i++ % 2 == 0) cout << c; });
```

output: `Hlool`

Answer (score 0):

You could go with something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < scrambleword.length(); i+=2){
        output += scrambleword.at(i);
}
```

Comment: Why range checking through `at`? You cannot get out of range, so prefer (non-checking) index `operator[]`.